# How to get Site Collection list from tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

we need to get Site collection/Webs under tenant in a Webpart
Here is the TSX file code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './GetSpWebs.module.scss';
import { IGetSpWebsProps } from './IGetSpWebsProps';
//import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import * as jquery from 'jquery';

export interface IRGetSpWebsWPState { getlistitems: [{ "Title": "" }] }

export default class GetSpWebs extends React.Component<IGetSpWebsProps, IRGetSpWebsWPState> {
  static siteurl: string = "";

  public constructor(props: IGetSpWebsProps, state: IRGetSpWebsWPState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      getlistitems: [{ "Title": "" }]
    };
    GetSpWebs.siteurl = this.props.webSiteUrl;
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    let reactcontexthandler = this;
    jquery.ajax({
      url: `https://4spq36-admin.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS')/items?$select=Title,SiteUrl`,
      type: "GET",
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json; odata =verbose;' },
      success: function (resultData) {
        reactcontexthandler.setState({

          getlistitems: resultData.d.results
        });
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorthrown) {

      }
    });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpWebsProps> {

    return (
      <div>
        <h3 className={styles.h3}>SiteCollection webs List Using ReactJS</h3>

        <table className={styles.table}>
          <tr>
            <th className={styles.th}>{"Title"}</th>
          </tr>
          {
            this.state.getlistitems.map(function (listitem, listitemkey) {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td className={styles.td}> {listitem.Title}</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          }</table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the above piece of code shows 403 error please find the screen shot below
[image]

If i try to access the REST API in the browser its working fine i can able to get required data, but i use the same API in the SPFX webpart which is showing 403 status error.
Any assistance please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  /***** This is Webpart.tsx file *****/  
import * as React from 'react';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
/*** use the context in this file ****/
export interface IExpProps {
  context: WebPartContext;

}
export default class Exp extends React.Component<IExpProps, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      Sites: [],
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(): void {
    debugger;
    const webUrl: string = this.props.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl
    const requestUrl = `${webUrl}/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web'&selectproperties='Title,Path'&rowlimit=500
    `;
    let siteUrl :any=[]
    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            const sites: any[] = data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows
            if (sites){
            for (let i = 0; i <= sites.length; i++) {
              const url=sites[i].Cells.find((cell: any) => cell.Key === 'Path').Value
             console.log("sites and Subsites",url)
             siteUrl.push({
              Url:url
             })
             this.setState({Sites:siteUrl})
            }
          }
            console.log(this.state.Sites)

          });
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
      });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IExpProps> {
    return (
      <div>Sites:
        <ol>
          {this.state.Sites.map((items:any) => {
            return [
              <li>{items.Url}</li>
            ]
          })}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
/******* This is webpart.ts file *****/
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { IReadonlyTheme } from '@microsoft/sp-component-base';

import * as strings from 'ExpWebPartStrings';
import Exp from './components/Exp';
import { IExpProps } from './components/IExpProps';

export interface IExpWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class ExpWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IExpWebPartProps> {

  private _isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
  private _environmentMessage: string = '';

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IExpProps> = React.createElement(
      Exp,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        isDarkTheme: this._isDarkTheme,
        environmentMessage: this._environmentMessage,
        hasTeamsContext: !!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams,
        userDisplayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName,
        context:this.context /**** Mention the context here ***/
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return this._getEnvironmentMessage().then(message => {
      this._environmentMessage = message;
    });
  }



  private _getEnvironmentMessage(): Promise<string> {
    if (!!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) { // running in Teams, office.com or Outlook
      return this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.teamsJs.app.getContext()
        .then(context => {
          let environmentMessage: string = '';
          switch (context.app.host.name) {
            case 'Office': // running in Office
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentOffice : strings.AppOfficeEnvironment;
              break;
            case 'Outlook': // running in Outlook
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentOutlook : strings.AppOutlookEnvironment;
              break;
            case 'Teams': // running in Teams
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentTeams : strings.AppTeamsTabEnvironment;
              break;
            default:
              throw new Error('Unknown host');
          }

          return environmentMessage;
        });
    }

    return Promise.resolve(this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentSharePoint : strings.AppSharePointEnvironment);
  }

  protected onThemeChanged(currentTheme: IReadonlyTheme | undefined): void {
    if (!currentTheme) {
      return;
    }

    this._isDarkTheme = !!currentTheme.isInverted;
    const {
      semanticColors
    } = currentTheme;

    if (semanticColors) {
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--bodyText', semanticColors.bodyText || null);
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--link', semanticColors.link || null);
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--linkHovered', semanticColors.linkHovered || null);
    }

  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
/******* This is Props.ts file *****/
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

export interface IExpProps {
  description: string;
  isDarkTheme: boolean;
  environmentMessage: string;
  hasTeamsContext: boolean;
  userDisplayName: string;
  context:WebPartContext; /****  Declare here context *****/
}
```

Comment: Really appreciated, Solution is working fine. this is code is really helps me a lot, thanks for help

Comment: Hi @Vaishnavi, is there a way to loop subsites as well? means what if Site collection has subSites ? Is there way to loop subsites under a siteCollection ?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the Graph API to return all sites in the tenant:

[List sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Here is some additional information on consuming the Microsoft Graph API from SPFx:

[Consume the Microsoft Graph in the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial)

Comment: May be but bit odds to me any way please help me if there is any link on how to call Graph API call from SPFX please assist me.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please remember to upvote/mark as answer where appropriate to help the community.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IWebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, ISPHttpClientOptions } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

export interface ISiteCollection {
  siteUrl: string;
  siteTitle: string;
}

export interface ISiteCollectionsWebPartProps {
  context: IWebPartContext;
}

export default class SiteCollectionsWebPart extends React.Component<ISiteCollectionsWebPartProps, any> {
  constructor(props: ISiteCollectionsWebPartProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      siteCollections: []
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.getSiteCollections();
  }

  private getSiteCollections(): void {
    const endpointUrl = `${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site'`;

    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(endpointUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Error ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (data && data.PrimaryQueryResult && data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults &&
          data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table && data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows) {
          const siteCollections: ISiteCollection[] = data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.map(row => {
            const siteUrl = row.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Path').Value;
            const siteTitle = row.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Title').Value;
            return { siteUrl, siteTitle };
          });
          this.setState({ siteCollections });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching site collections:', error);
      });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISiteCollectionsWebPartProps> {
    const { siteCollections } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Site Collections</h1>
        <ul>
          {siteCollections.map((site: ISiteCollection) => (
            <li key={site.siteUrl}>
              <a href={site.siteUrl}>{site.siteTitle}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vinothkumar Really appreciate for piece of code Can I request you to update code in-between ``` your code ``` this will align properly

Comment: Hi @Vinoth the code which you posted also working fine, but there is an error from my solution that is at ```ISiteCollection[]   and  row => and  cell =>```, after I carefully these are very minor issues, but after compare with above solution both are working fine. thanks for help